# Media Query for HTML5 App for All Devices

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, media-queries

**Any one Have Idea , about all media queries 
that will help to detect individual devices such as:**

*iOS,iPhone 5 , iPhone Ratina display , android mobile. , ipad, tablets atc ?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

go for [**media-queries-for-standard-devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

For Retina Display use

```
@media 
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks bhai .. also need to detect ratina display.

Comment: @iDevTechnolab: i have added it too now..!!

Comment: @iDevTechnolab:check this too http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/

Comment: do you have any template for mobile app UI?