# How and where to add code to make a website responsive fit to all screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, portfolio

### I have a quite dynamic file and trying to make this [web](http://bunnymugsy.xyz) responsive, fit to all screen... can anybody help?

I tried with skeleton css and also tried with different coding, but all failed. Since I started with Stacey Template in early time, it's quite tricky for me to handle it with basic knowledge of HTML&CSS.

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to look at css3 media queries.

Comment: how did you try with the skeleton css?

Comment: your question had been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374550/media-query-for-html5-app-for-all-devices

Comment: The answer I included is to give you the meat on how this works.  Bootstrap is decent to work from, but people generally use it without knowing how it does things, so when something looks weird, they have no idea how to fix it.  There are other projects as well if working from scratch.  If just converting something existing, it's usually trivial to make it responsive without having to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)!  Its popular and free!

The [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) allows your site to be responsive to mobile devices, tables, and desktops

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for code, and how to make a non-responsive website using an existing website without having to do a complete rewrite (depending on circumstances), what you see is CSS declarations, in combination with adding a header in HTML to inform the browser that this site will conform to dimensions as you specify and a default dimension set.

Typically, this is done by putting the larger form of the website first (eg, the default view), and then working downward.  Some people adopt this in reverse using a 'mobile first' method meaning the site is initially designed for mobile, and the CSS is then adjusted for size from smallest screen size to biggest screen size.

The example below is working from large size down to small screen. Anything less than 800px, is styled to show up well on all mobile devices. Please note, this is only a snippet taken out of context of a larger site, however this should suffice as to the meat of what you are trying to do.

HTML portion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- your other code and js / etc here -->
    <head>
    <body>
         <!-- content -->
    </body>

    <!-- place slow loading javascripts here -->
</html>
```

CSS Example :

```
/*  Global styles  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  Style override when screen is less than 1600px wide  */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .col { margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .col:nth-child(2) { margin-left: 2%; clear: right; }
    .col:nth-child(4) { margin-left: 2%; clear: right; }
    .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 48%; margin-bottom: 20px; }
}

/*  Style override when screen is less than 800px wide  */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; clear: both; }
    .col:nth-child(2) { margin-left: 0%; }
    .col:nth-child(4) { margin-left: 0%; }
    .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```